# Create a jquery / html5 canvas graph

Tags: jquery, html, graph

So I need to create a graph that basically looks like an ascending line graph.
on the x-axis will be time, and on the y-axis will be achievements that the user has unlocked.
Each achievement shown will be a specified height above the previous, and a certain distance across the x-axis depending when they were unlocked.

What would be the best method to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://processingjs.org/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HighCharts](http://highcharts.com/). Or, [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) for a more powerful solution. These libraries works using SVG.

Here there is [an example using HighCharts](http://jsfiddle.net/sGhbu/).

Comment: I've already used Highcharts but I want something very basic and simple that's very customisable.

Comment: Okay so I didn't look at Raphael, my bad - looks amazing. I'm going to give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can visit this site for canvas tutorials like charts.

[canvas tutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/)